# How to install libpng12-0 on Debian 10 buster i386?

Tags: linux, debian

I added repository "deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main" (i used [this](https://packages.debian.org/ru/jessie/i386/libpng12-0/download)).
I started the installation:

```
sudo apt install libpng12-0
```

But the error comes out:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_i386.deb (--unpack):
Failed to install new version “/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0”: No such file or directory
Errors occurred while processing the following packages:
/var/cache/apt/archives/libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_i386.deb
E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I extracted file `libpng12.so.0` from this package and placed it in directory `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/`.

But at installation start:
    sudo apt install libpng12-0
the same error comes out.
In this case, file `libpng12.so.0` in directory `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` disappears.

If I install the package via gdebi, the error is as follows:

```
/usr/bin/gdebi:113: FutureWarning: Possible nested set at position 1
c = findall("[[(](\S+)/\S+[])]", msg)[0].lower()
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming and belongs to [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: I'll try to ask there.
It's just that there are similar questions on SOF.

Comment: Sorry I didn't want to sound offensive or so. It's just for this kind of question there's a better chance to get it answered well on SU. And yes, there are definitely many of those questions here on SO, but they are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am our answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/331803/cannot-install-libpng12-0-on-debian?newreg=797d99ca0c6f46efba44e105abb8847b).
Deliver this package from repositories Debian 7 wheezy.

Comment: Can confirm this also worked on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Can be downloaded from an archive mirror as libpng12-0_1.2.49-1+deb7u2_xxxxx.deb: http://debian.snt.utwente.nl/debian-archive/debian/pool/main/libp/libpng/